# Bridging LXC containers to host eth0 so they can have a public IP

Tags: networking, iptables, bridge, lxc

UPDATE:

I found the solution there:
http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/bridge#No_traffic_gets_trough_.28except_ARP_and_STP.29

```
 # cd /proc/sys/net/bridge
 # ls
 bridge-nf-call-arptables  bridge-nf-call-iptables
 bridge-nf-call-ip6tables  bridge-nf-filter-vlan-tagged
 # for f in bridge-nf-*; do echo 0 > $f; done
```

But I'd like to have expert opinions on this: is it safe to disable all bridge-nf-*? What are they here for?

END OF UPDATE

I need to bridge LXC containers to the physical interface (eth0) of my host, reading numerous tutorials, documents and blog posts on the subject.

I need the containers to have their own public IP (which I've previously done KVM/libvirt).

After two days of searching and trying, I still can't make it work with LXC containers.

The host runs a freshly installed Ubuntu Server Quantal (12.10) with only libvirt (which I'm not using here) and lxc installed.

I created the containers with :

```
lxc-create -t ubuntu -n mycontainer
```

So they also run Ubuntu 12.10.

Content of /var/lib/lxc/mycontainer/config is:

```
lxc.utsname = mycontainer
lxc.mount = /var/lib/lxc/test/fstab
lxc.rootfs = /var/lib/lxc/test/rootfs


lxc.network.type = veth
lxc.network.flags = up
lxc.network.link = br0
lxc.network.name = eth0
lxc.network.veth.pair = vethmycontainer
lxc.network.ipv4 = 179.43.46.233
lxc.network.hwaddr= 02:00:00:86:5b:11

lxc.devttydir = lxc
lxc.tty = 4
lxc.pts = 1024
lxc.arch = amd64
lxc.cap.drop = sys_module mac_admin mac_override
lxc.pivotdir = lxc_putold

# uncomment the next line to run the container unconfined:
#lxc.aa_profile = unconfined

lxc.cgroup.devices.deny = a
# Allow any mknod (but not using the node)
lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = c *:* m
lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = b *:* m
# /dev/null and zero
lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = c 1:3 rwm
lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = c 1:5 rwm
# consoles
lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = c 5:1 rwm
lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = c 5:0 rwm
#lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = c 4:0 rwm
#lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = c 4:1 rwm
# /dev/{,u}random
lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = c 1:9 rwm
lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = c 1:8 rwm
lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = c 136:* rwm
lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = c 5:2 rwm
# rtc
lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = c 254:0 rwm
#fuse
lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = c 10:229 rwm
#tun
lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = c 10:200 rwm
#full
lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = c 1:7 rwm
#hpet
lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = c 10:228 rwm
#kvm
lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = c 10:232 rwm
```

Then I changed my host /etc/network/interfaces to:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto br0
iface br0 inet static
        bridge_ports eth0
        bridge_fd 0
        address 92.281.86.226
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 92.281.86.0
        broadcast 92.281.86.255
        gateway 92.281.86.254
        dns-nameservers 213.186.33.99
        dns-search ovh.net
```

When I try command line configuration ("brctl addif", "ifconfig eth0", etc.) my remote host becomes inaccessible and I have to hard reboot it.

I changed the content of /var/lib/lxc/mycontainer/rootfs/etc/network/interfaces to:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 179.43.46.233
        netmask 255.255.255.255
        broadcast 178.33.40.233
        gateway 92.281.86.254
```

It takes several minutes for mycontainer to start (lxc-start -n mycontainer).

I tried replacing

```
        gateway 92.281.86.254
```

by :

```
        post-up route add 92.281.86.254 dev eth0
        post-up route add default gw 92.281.86.254
        post-down route del 92.281.86.254 dev eth0
        post-down route del default gw 92.281.86.254
```

My container then starts instantly.

But whatever configuration I set in /var/lib/lxc/mycontainer/rootfs/etc/network/interfaces, I cannot ping from mycontainer to any IP (including the host's) :

```
ubuntu@mycontainer:~$ ping 92.281.86.226 
PING 92.281.86.226 (92.281.86.226) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 92.281.86.226 ping statistics ---
6 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 5031ms
```

And my host cannot ping the container:

```
root@host:~# ping 179.43.46.233
PING 179.43.46.233 (179.43.46.233) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 179.43.46.233 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 4000ms
```

My container's ifconfig:

```
ubuntu@mycontainer:~$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:00:00:86:5b:11  
          inet addr:179.43.46.233  Bcast:255.255.255.255  Mask:0.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::ff:fe79:5a31/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:64 errors:0 dropped:6 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:54 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:4070 (4.0 KB)  TX bytes:4168 (4.1 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:32 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:32 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:2496 (2.4 KB)  TX bytes:2496 (2.4 KB)
```

My host's ifconfig:

```
root@host:~# ifconfig
br0       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 4c:72:b9:43:65:2b  
          inet addr:92.281.86.226  Bcast:91.121.67.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::4e72:b9ff:fe43:652b/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1453 errors:0 dropped:18 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1630 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:145125 (145.1 KB)  TX bytes:299943 (299.9 KB)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 4c:72:b9:43:65:2b  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3178 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1637 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:298263 (298.2 KB)  TX bytes:309167 (309.1 KB)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:fe500000-fe520000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:6 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:300 (300.0 B)  TX bytes:300 (300.0 B)

vethtest  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fe:0d:7f:3e:70:88  
          inet6 addr: fe80::fc0d:7fff:fe3e:7088/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:54 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:67 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:4168 (4.1 KB)  TX bytes:4250 (4.2 KB)

virbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr de:49:c5:66:cf:84  
          inet addr:192.168.122.1  Bcast:192.168.122.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

I have disabled lxcbr0 (USE_LXC_BRIDGE="false" in /etc/default/lxc).

```
root@host:~# brctl show
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces                                                                                                 
br0             8000.4c72b943652b       no              eth0                                                                                                       
                                                        vethtest
```

I have configured the IP 179.43.46.233 to point to 02:00:00:86:5b:11 in my hosting provider (OVH) config panel.
(The IPs in this post are not the real ones.)

Thanks for reading this long question! :-)

Vianney

Answer (score 6):

A better way to make your change permanent is to use sysctl instead of writing to /proc directly since that is the standard way to configure kernel parameters at runtime so they are set correctly at next boot:

```
# cat >> /etc/sysctl.d/99-bridge-nf-dont-pass.conf <<EOF
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables = 0
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables = 0
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-arptables = 0
net.bridge.bridge-nf-filter-vlan-tagged = 0
EOF
# service procps start
```

As for the answer to the question in your update...

[bridge-netfilter (or bridge-nf)](http://ebtables.sourceforge.net/documentation/bridge-nf.html) is a very simple bridge for IPv4/IPv6/ARP packets (even in 802.1Q VLAN or PPPoE headers) that provides the functionality for a stateful transparent firewall, but more advanced functionality like transparent IP NAT is provided by passing those packets to arptables/iptables for further processing-- **however even if the more advanced features of arptables/iptables is not need, passing packets to those programs is still turned on by default in the kernel module and must be turned off explicitly using sysctl.**

**What are they here for?** These kernel configuration options are here to either pass (1) or don't pass (0) packets to arptables/iptables as described in the [bridge-nf FAQ](http://ebtables.sourceforge.net/misc/brnf-faq.html):

```
As of kernel version 2.6.1, there are three sysctl entries for bridge-nf behavioral control (they can be found under /proc/sys/net/bridge/):
bridge-nf-call-arptables - pass (1) or don't pass (0) bridged ARP traffic to arptables' FORWARD chain.
bridge-nf-call-iptables - pass (1) or don't pass (0) bridged IPv4 traffic to iptables' chains.
bridge-nf-call-ip6tables - pass (1) or don't pass (0) bridged IPv6 traffic to ip6tables' chains.
bridge-nf-filter-vlan-tagged - pass (1) or don't pass (0) bridged vlan-tagged ARP/IP traffic to arptables/iptables.
```

**Is it safe to disable all bridge-nf-*?** Yes, it is not only safe to do so, but there is a [recommendation for distributions to turn it off by default](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=512206#c0) to help people **avoid confusion** for the kind of problem you encountered:

> In practice, this can lead to serious confusion where someone creates
>   a bridge and finds that some traffic isn't being forwarded across the
>   bridge. Because it's so unexpected that IP firewall rules apply to
>   frames on a bridge, it can take quite some time to figure out what's
>   going on.

and to **increase security**:

> I still think the risk with bridging is higher, especially   in the
>   presence of virtualisation.  Consider the scenario where you   have two
>   VMs on the one host, each with a dedicated bridge with the   intention
>   that neither should know anything about the other's   traffic.
>
> With conntrack running as part of bridging, the traffic can now
>   cross over which is a serious security hole.

**UPDATE: May 2015**

If you are running a kernel older than 3.18, then you may be subject to the old behavior of bridge filtering enabled by default; if you newer than 3.18, then you can still be bitten by this if you've loaded the bridge module and haven't disabled the bridge filtering. See:

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=634736#c44

> After all these years of asking for the default of bridge filtering to
>   be "disabled" and the change being refused by the kernel maintainers,
>   now the filtering has been moved into a separate module that isn't
>   loaded (by default) when the bridge module is loaded, effectively
>   making the default "disabled". Yay!
>
> I *think* this is in the kernel as of 3.17 (It definitely is in kernel
>   3.18.7-200.fc21, and appears to be in git prior to the tag "v3.17-rc4")

Answer (score 0):

I've got a similar set up running on a Debian Wheezy hypervisor. I didn't have to modify /etc/network/interfaces within the container's rootfs; having lxc.network.* configured in LXC's config is sufficient.

You should be able to get bridging working irrespective of whether you're running a container or not. I have the following settings configured under br0 in /etc/network/interfaces on the host:

```
% grep bridge /etc/network/interfaces
  bridge_ports eth0
  bridge_fd 0
  bridge_stp off
  bridge_waitport 0
  bridge_maxwait 0
```

After configuring this and moving my IP address configuration from eth0 to br0, `sudo service networking restart` transparently reconfigured the interfaces on my host machine without dropping my SSH session.

Once that's done, try removing the 'eth0' configuration in /etc/network/interfaces and restarting your container.