# Setting up bridged LXC containers with static IPs

Tags: networking, bridge, static-ip, lxc

I'm trying to setup multiple LXC containers on a host, each with public static IPs of their own.

My host is running the latest Ubuntu.  It has a single network interface named eth0.  The static IPs are pingable from the internet and are named eth0:210, eth0:211...  The numbers after the colon are the least significant byte of the addresses.  In addition to these interfaces I have br0 setup on the host's public IP.  There are also the lo, veth2LPP9A, and lxcbr0 interfaces.  The lxcbr0 has the address of a private IP.

The host /etc/network/interfaces looks like:

```
auto br0
iface br0 inet static
        bridge_ports eth0
        bridge_fd 0
        [...]
```

So far I've used various online sources, including [Bridging LXC containers to host eth0 so they can have a public IP](https://serverfault.com/questions/445991/bridging-lxc-containers-to-host-eth0-so-they-can-have-a-public-ip) to help me set this up.

The container's config file has:

```
lxc.network.type = veth
lxc.network.link = br0
```

I've removed the static lxc.network.ipv4 configuration from this file since it caused problems.  When I ran lxc-ls --fancy with this configuration, I'd see the same public IP twice in the output.  Additionally, it would mess with the subnet configuration of the container's /etc/network/interfaces.

Speaking of the container's interfaces file, it looks a bit like:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address [...]
        netmask 255.255.255.255
        #gateway [...]
        dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8

        post-up route add [...] dev eth0
        post-up route add default gw [...]
        post-down route del [...] dev eth0
        post-down route del default gw [...]
```

I had to comment out the gateway and add the route add commands to this file.  Otherwise, the container would take minutes to boot.

The /proc/sys/net/bridge/bridge-nf-* files on the host are all set to 0.  The /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward value is 1.

The problem is, even though the container's "route -n" looks like it should, I can't ping out of the container.  SSHing to what should be the container's IP, connects me to the host.

EDIT: Removing the container's static IP from the host did help, but now I'm getting a new error.  Trying to ping the container from the host results in Redirect HostFrom , New nexthop.  The packets are just going from the gateway to the host, repeatedly.  Running a traceroute from the host shows that the first stop is at the gateway.  Then all of the other routes are * * *.  I get the same problem regardless if the container is online or not.

Answer (score 18):

In fact you **can** set the address and gateway from **within** the **host** and configure the container not to touch the interface at all using the keyword [`manual`](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=interfaces&sektion=5).

Place this within the guests `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual
```

Also leave it up to the container's config file to set up the interface:

```
lxc.network.type = veth
lxc.network.flags = up
lxc.network.link = lxc-bridge-nat
lxc.network.ipv4 = 192.168.100.16/24
lxc.network.ipv4.gateway = auto
```

The guest will behave like it's BIOS already set up the interface and just use it.

Especially explore [`lxc.network.ipv4.gateway`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man5/lxc.container.conf.5.html).

Comment: Thx! This saved my life... my container would always try to get a new dhcp address... setting it to a fixed value inside the container (static) resulted in the container not even booting anymore!

Comment: Note that this doesn't work well if the host is suspended and resumed. The lxc continues with its allocated ip-address but the host thinks it doesn't have an ip-address anymore. I have found it is better to configure the dnsmasq for lxc-net and handout a fixed address there.

Comment: @HRJ - You should include the 'how' in your comment or link to the ref rather than just saying 'do it'. This is a technical site and you should say something actually useable.

Comment: It seems like the correct place to do this is both in /etc/default/lxc where you can set your range (see LXC_DHCP_RANGE) and in /etc/dnsmasq.d-available/lxc as per the dnsmasq docs or manpage

Comment: See [How to let built-in DHCP assign a static IP to LXC container based on name, not MAC address](http://askubuntu.com/questions/446831/how-to-let-built-in-dhcp-assign-a-static-ip-to-lxc-container-based-on-name-not)

Comment: very nice answer but should be updated for LXC 3

Answer (score 5):

Since you are bridging, you need to set the IP addresses in the container *only*, and not on the host. The host should only have *its own* IP address(es).

Answer (score 4):

The best way I find and the quickest is to use the lxc profiles

`lxc profile list` - command the list all the profiles you have
Then

`lxc profile copy default minecraft`(this is the name of your new profile)

Then  `lxc profile edit minecraft`

This will come up

```
devices:
  eth0:
    ipv4.address: 192.168.1.114/24  - add this line and enter any ip address you like
    name: eth0
    nictype: macvlan - this is my setting
    parent: enp0s25
    type: nic
  root:
    path: /
    pool: lxc_zfs
    type: disk
name: mine
used_by:
```

then save it

next assign the profile to your LXC container like this

```
lxc profile assign YOUR_CONTAINER_NAME YOUR_NEW_PROFILE_NAME
```

then just restart the container and your new ip address is set to that container

Comment: I was looking for a solution for macvlan, so thanks for your suggestion.  However, this  seems so wrong because a profile is shared across all containers using that profile.  So, for it to work you will have to make multiple copies of a shared profile, and use one profile per container.  Now, imagine that you have tens of containers ... LOL.  

Oh well, I will have to live with dhcp assigned addresses for now ...

Answer (score 2):

I just did it the other day with Ubuntu 14.04. It is simple. You just have to edit the `/etc/network/interfaces` file inside your container, and set this:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
 address $IP
 netmask $NETMASK
 gateway $GW
 dns-nameservers $DNS
```

Replace every variable with the desired value.

You **DON'T** have to do anything else!

PS: Notice the space before some lines. It is mandatory.

Comment: this resulted in my container not booting anymore (ubuntu 14.04 server).. the answer from sebastianwagner works for me.

Answer (score 1):

I could set up correctly my lxc containers after following @Enrique Moreno Tent's answer, so I will explain what to do in more details in case you don't know how to set up the other items.

### 1. Access your LXC container via `lxc-attach` command

Command:

`$ lxc-attach -n YOUR-CONTAINER-NAME`

### 2. See your current configurations with `ifconfig`

Command

```
root@mycontainer:~# ifconfig
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.3.160  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.3.255
        inet6 fe80::216:3eff:fec9:2fa0  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:16:3e:c9:2f:a0  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 62  bytes 7142 (7.1 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 60  bytes 9788 (9.7 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 20285  bytes 175021803 (175.0 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 20285  bytes 175021803 (175.0 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

```

### 3. Getting address, netmask and gateway

Seeing the result of the `ifconfig` command above, we then see:

**Address** is the address you want, you can change it to 10.0.3.166.

**Netmask** is there: 255.255.255.0

**Gateway**: For the gateway you use the **broadcast** address with here is 10.0.3.255

As you can see above, you currently have all information you need to fill your guest (container) `/etc/network/interfaces`.

### 4. Getting `dns-nameservers` value.

Issue the command:

`cat /etc/resolv.conf`

But maybe is best using Google DNS, which asre `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4`

### 5. Editing `/etc/network/interfaces` INSIDE THE CONTAINER

`auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
 address 10.0.3.166
 netmask 255.255.255.0
 gateway 10.0.3.255
 dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8`

Comment: `ifconfig` has been replaced with `ip a` in more recent debian/ubuntu versions https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-missing-ifconfig-command-on-debian-linux