# How to set the dns on lxc containers staticly?

Tags: domain-name-system, lxc, static-ip

I am trying to set the dns manually to a lxc container.
I already read your comments on 
[[Setting up bridged LXC containers with static IPs](https://serverfault.com/questions/571714/setting-up-bridged-lxc-containers-with-static-ips/586577][1])
But this did not work with me.

In etc/network/interfaces inside the container I tried:

> auto eth0
>
> iface eth0 inet manual

and I tried

> auto eth0
>
> iface eth0 inet static
>
> address 10.1.5.2
>
> netmask 255.255.255.0
>
> gateway 10.1.5.1
>
> dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8

But this did not work. I still have dns problems that I still receive the foloowing message when using apt-get

> Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'

Answer (score 1):

Just get it ...

In the container all what we need is to add dns to /etc/resolv.conf

> echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" | sudo tee /etc/resolv.conf > /dev/null

Comment: Please accept your own answer to mark this question as "solved"